# Markdown output for Sphinx based documentation

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I found myself with a use case, where in addition to generating HTML and PDF from my [*Sphinx*](http://sphinx-doc.org) based documentation sources, I would also like to generate a [*Markdown*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) version of the [*reStructuredText*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText) source files.

My preliminary research didn't find any core or extension support for this in *Sphinx*. Other than manually using [*pandoc*](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) or creating a new *Sphinx* extension for the task, is there be a simpler/more integrated solution for this?

Comment: I haven't seen any existing extension. Before your second paragraph, my first idea was to suggest Pandoc :-) So I guess that's your best bet.

Comment: @ReinoutvanRees: I am using pandoc at moment. Maybe I'll probe the Sphinx community to see if there is any interest in implementing something like this and give it a go. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using sphinx with Markdown instead of RST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471804/using-sphinx-with-markdown-instead-of-rst)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I didn't find anything which could take reStructuredText files and convert them to Markdown except for Pandoc, so I wrote a custom writer for [Docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/) (the reference implementation of reStructuredText and what Sphinx is built upon). The code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/cgwrench/rst2md).

Note that it is only an initial implementation: it handles any reStructuredText document without error (tested against the *standard.txt* test document from the Docutils source repository) but many of the reStructuredText constructs (e.g. substitutions, raw directives etc.) are not supported and so not included in the Markdown output. I hope to add support for links, code blocks, images and tables: any help towards this is more than welcome - just go ahead and fork the code.

It seems that to add another writer/output format to Sphinx you need to [add a "builder"](http://sphinx-doc.org/builders.html#builders) using an [extension](http://sphinx-doc.org/extensions.html#extensions).

Comment: Thanks, Chris for getting this started. I created a builder extension for this. https://github.com/codejamninja/sphinx-markdown-builder

Answer (score 26):

*Update Nov'18*: ***sphinx-markdown-builder*** is now available - thanks to @Jam Risser :

**Installation**

```
pip3 install sphinx-markdown-builder
```

**Dependencies**

Python 3

**Usage**

Load extension in configuration.

conf.py

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx_markdown_builder'
]
```

If using *recommonmark*, make sure you explicitly ignore the build files as they will conflict with the system.

conf.py

```
exclude_patterns = [
    'build/*'
]
```

Build markdown files with Makefile

```
make markdown
```

Build markdown files with sphinx-build command

```
cd docs
sphinx-build -M markdown ./ build
```

**References**

- https://github.com/codejamninja/sphinx-markdown-builder/
- https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-markdown-builder/

ps. Outdated original answer (since `sphinx-markdown-builder` is now available): 
Created feature request for direct Markdown output support on Sphinx project site:
https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4219
Thanks everyone who upvoted that github request - that made the difference!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use pandoc why won't you simply change the Makefile Sphinx generates when you run sphinx-quickstart.py for the first time to convert the reStructuredText to Markdown?
It's the easiest solution, although Chris's solution should work as well if you incorporate it into the Makefile.