# restructuredText docstrings to .md files

Tags: python, markdown, documentation, restructuredtext

I have a Python project where i used restructuredText to comment/documentate each of my classes/functions. Here's a sample of my docstring :

```
"""
Updates the contacts birth date in batch
:param nb_contacts: nb_contacts: number of contacts to update
:param batch_size: size of the batch
:param context: airflow context
:return: true if update is successful
"""
```

I wanna generate .md files from my code. Is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Just looking for something that can be well displayed on git and a human readable .md doc files. A doc that has the same structure as the .html documentation generated with sphinx but in .md files

Comment: Please note that comments and docstrings are two different things. What you have in the question is a docstring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sphinx](https://sphinx.io) is probably what you are looking for, additionally it is possible to publish the generated documentation to [ReadTheDocs](https://readthedocs.org/), which you are probably familiar with already.

Any `.rst` files can strictly be converted to `.md` (or any other format) with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org), where you would do something like:

`pandoc -f page.rst -t page.md`

Comment: But Sphinx only generates .rst files no ? Can we use convert those .rst files to markdown ?

Comment: @Arès Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generating Markdown from reStructuredText appears to be an uncommon combination.  You'll find a question similar to yours on [Markdown output for Sphinx based documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396856/markdown-output-for-sphinx-based-documentation)