# Whole site compilation of markdown/pandoc?

Tags: documentation, markdown, pandoc, pelican

With [Sphinx-doc](http://sphinx-doc.org/), you can create a bunch of ReStructureText files, with an `index.rst` file which includes a table of contents macro that auto generates a table of contents from the other included files, and a `conf.py` that acts as a compilation config. You can then compile the lot into a single python-doc-style site, complete with index, navigation tools, and a search function.

Is there any comparable tool for markdown (preferably pandoc-style markdown)?

Comment: Is there also some (markdown) documentation tool, which can produce PDF and ePub as easy as Sphinx does?

Comment: @white_gecko Edit in [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#overview), convert to XHTML with [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) and lastly convert to PDF with [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/), which you may or may not use for free (see [CSO license](http://www.princexml.com/license/)). Again, check out [my website](http://hamwaves.com/cl-ocfd/en/index.html) for details. There is an open-source alternative called [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which is not good at page breaking though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Some static site generators that work with Markdown**:

- [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) is very popular and also the engine behind [GitHub pages](http://pages.github.com/).
- Python variants: [Hyde](http://ringce.com/hyde) or [Pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.1.1/)
- [nanoc](http://nanoc.ws/) (used f.ex. in the [GitHub API documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/))
- [Middlemanapp](http://middlemanapp.com/): maybe the best one?

I think none of them use pandoc (maybe because it's written in Haskell), but they all use an enhanced Markdown syntax or can be configured to use pandoc.

**Other interesting ways to generate a site from markdown:**

- Markdown-*Wikis* that are file based: f.ex. [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum), the Wiki-Engine that is also used by GitHub
- [Telegram](https://telegr.am/index): commercial; written by David Pollak, the inventor the Lift-Scala-framework

**Engines that use Pandoc:**

- [Gitit](https://github.com/jgm/gitit): Pandoc Wiki
- [Hakyll](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/): Haskell library to generate static sites
- [Pandoc-Plugin forIkiwiki](https://github.com/dubiousjim/pandoc-iki)
- [Yst static site generator](http://github.com/jgm/yst)
- [Gouda - generates a site from a directory of markdown files](http://www.unexpected-vortices.com/sw/gouda/)
- [Rippledoc - generates a navigable site from nested directories of markdown files](http://unexpected-vortices.com/sw/rippledoc/)

**The definitive listing of Static Site Generators**

A good overview of static site generators: http://staticsitegenerators.net/

Comment: Hyde is basically a CMS, right? I don't want something that I have to leave runnning. Some of the others look interesting though, thanks for the list!

Comment: As far as I know Hyde produce also static HTML just like Jekyll.

Comment: For those coming after me: Pelican is cool, but it's aimed at a blog, rather than a static site, as sphinx is.

Comment: @naught101 What did you go for in the end? I am looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 10):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html), the GNU [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) commands, sprinkled with some [CSS](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) are all you need to fully automate the creation of a static website starting from [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#overview).

Pandoc offers three command line options which can provide navigation between pages as well as the creation of a table of contents (TOC) based on the headings inside the page. With CSS you can make the navigation and TOC look and behave the way you want.

> -B FILE, --include-before-body=FILE
>
> Include contents of FILE, verbatim, at the beginning of the document body (e.g. after the  tag in HTML, or the \begin{document} command in LaTeX). This can be used to include navigation bars or banners in HTML documents. This option can be used repeatedly to include multiple files. They will be included in the order specified. Implies --standalone.
>
> --toc, --table-of-contents
>
> Include an automatically generated table of contents.
>
> --toc-depth=NUMBER
>
> Specify the number of section levels to include in the table of contents.
>      The default is 3 (which means that level 1, 2, and 3 headers will be listed in the contents).

As a matter of fact, [my personal website is built this way](http://hamwaves.com/gedit/en/index.html). Check out its [makefile](http://hamwaves.com/pandoc/article/en/makefile) for more details. It is all free-libre open-source licensed under the [GNU GPL version 3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html).

Comment: Er... those TOC options relate to the headers *within* a markdown file. I'm talking about a TOC across multiple files, each a separate page. Your personal website is a single page...

Comment: @naught101 I have edited my answer. Navigation between pages can easily be handled with the `--include-before-body=FILE` option.

Comment: No, you're missing the point. Sphinx-doc lets you write multiple pages *as separate files*, and then generates an HTML file for each page (with a TOC in the side bar), as well as a full-page TOC html file (that doesn't have an .rst source, but it automatically generated). That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: @naught101 Then Sphinx-doc is indeed doing more than some of the engines (Gouda, Rippledoc,...) cited by the original poster.

Comment: on4aa: I am the OP. I see the lack of clarity in the question though, and have edited it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK not using Pandoc, [mkdocs](http://www.mkdocs.org/) would seem to fit your needs.

If you definitely want to use Pandoc-flavoured Markdown, you could check out [pdsite](http://pdsite.org). I wrote it as a way to get mkdocs-style site generation with more input formats (like emacs org-mode) and without the Python dependencies - you pass in a folder of Markdown files and get out an HTML site (including automatically-generated multi-level navigation links). It's similar to Serge Stroobandt's approach in that it's just a shell script (it does require you to have `tree` installed however).  Unfortunately it doesn't have a search function yet, although that wouldn't be too hard to add...