# How well does Weblate integrate with Wiki.js and git?

Tags: python-sphinx, weblate, wiki.js

Weblate has a detailed explanation on "[Translating documentation using Sphinx.](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/devel/sphinx.html#translating-documentation-using-sphinx)" Currently, I am using [wiki.js](https://js.wiki/) and Github. [Localise](https://lokalise.com/) integrates well with Wiki.js but I prefer Weblate, which is an open-source and self-hosted app.

I like how Wiki.js structure files and folders. Wiki.js has a nice inbuilt editor and also they store files in md format.

Though Sphinx has seamless integration with Weblate, I was wondering if Sphinx can use md files instead of rst file format.

Can we use Sphinx for internal documentation too or saving drafts?

Does Sphinx have user, group and permission features?

I am open to other alternatives to Wiki.js but it should have git integration.

Comment: Yes, Sphinx can use Markdown: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2471804/407651

Comment: "I am open to other alternatives...". Note that asking for software recommendations is off-topic. For such questions, go to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: See [MyST](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Sphinx does not have any authentication or authorization. It only renders static files. You must bring your own auth.

Answer (score 1):

Weblate has no native support for wiki.js. It has actually no native support for Sphinx either - Sphinx uses standard gettext PO files for localization, so all what is needed is documentation how to set it up. In case wiki.js has localization support built-in, it might work similarly (I have no knowledge of wiki.js to tell).

Markdown support is something planned in Weblate for a long time (see https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/issues/3106). AFAIR there was even some grant funding for that, but I have no clue if there is still some progress on that.

And yes, Sphinx can use Markdown files as well, but it will be probably challenging to combine Sphinx as renderer while still using wiki.js as editor.