# How to render Doxygen xml output into markdown instead of reST (using breathe or MyST-Parser)

Tags: c++, markdown, python-sphinx, doxygen, myst

I am preparing a project documentation using `Sphinx` where to fetch `Doxygen XML output` I have used [breathe](https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/directives.html#doxygenclass). I am using the breathe directive in `.rst` files.

`sample.cpp`

```cpp
namespace X{
class A{
   public:
       int x;
};
}
```

in my `rst` file I just added

```
.. doxygenclass:: X::A
   :members:
   :protected-members:
   :private-members:
```

After building the project I can see detailed documentation of `class A`. For some reason, I have the intention to use the `markdown` file instead of `.rst`.

I have gone through several posts but could not find any fruitful answer. The best one I have got [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67420551/10634362).

- I have installed [myst parser](https://pypi.org/project/myst-parser/)
- Modified `conf.py` by adding `extensions = ["myst_parser",]`

Written a `.md` file as like as follows:

````
# sample_md
```{doxygenclass:: X::A}
:members:
:protected-members:
:private-members:
```
````

But failed while the error message is

```
WARNING: unknown directive or role name: doxygenclass::A
/net/users/Linux_Home/user_name/project_name/doc/md_files/sample_mark.md:5: WARNING: Unknown directive type "doxygenclass::A".
```

Also tried

````
# sample_md
```{doxygenclass}
A
:members:
:protected-members:
:private-members:
```
````

Also failed and the error message

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/net/users/Linux_Home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/myst_parser/docutils_renderer.py", line 973, in run_directive
    if issubclass(directive_class, Include):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-guubfd6h.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!
make[2]: *** [doc/CMakeFiles/Sphinx.dir/build.make:63: doc/sphinx/index.html] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:215: doc/CMakeFiles/Sphinx.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

No idea what to do at this stage.

I have used following snipet in `.md` file

````
```{cpp:class} X::A
```
````

which has shown rendered class but only the name with a clickable link where no documentation of Doxygen XML is present. And I need that info.

Some of my observances are:

- [myST](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/markdown.html) is only for collecting `Sphinx directive` in markdown file
- [breathe](https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/directives.html#doxygenclass) is a tool to fetch `Doxygen XML output` and to write in `reST` style using `Sphinx`

Now my desire is to know, is it possible to add `breathe Doxygen directive` in the `.md` file? If Yes, where am I am making the syntax wrong?

Comment: When you say "but failed", what was the error?

Comment: I have added the corresponding error messages

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer [here](https://github.com/executablebooks/MyST-Parser/issues/323#issuecomment-788897173).

Now markdown file is as like as follows

````
```{eval-rst}
.. doxygenclass:: X::A
````

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

````
```{doxygenclass} X::A
:members:
:protected-members:
:private-members:
```
````

And if it fails, report the error?

Comment: Tried but failed.

`Exception occurred:
  File "/net/users/Linux_Home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/myst_parser/docutils_renderer.py", line 973, in run_directive
    if issubclass(directive_class, Include):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-rrzs5cm5.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!`

Comment: any idea on which end I will ask the question ([breathe](https://github.com/michaeljones/breathe), [myST](https://github.com/executablebooks/MyST-Parser), [Sphinx](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx))?

Comment: Try in MyST! Hopefully they'll answer quickly